# How did Arjuna know that Krishna would submerge Dwarka in the ocean before it happened?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, arjuna

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03012.htm

The relatives of the Pandavas visited them after they were banished.

> Vaisampayana said, 'Hearing that the Pandavas had been banished, the Bhojas, the Vrishnis, and the Andhakas went to those heroes residing in affliction in the great forest. And the consanguineous relatives of Panchala, and Dhrishtaketu the king of Chedi, and those celebrated and powerful brothers--the Kaikeyas, their hearts fired with wrath, went to the forest to see the sons of Pritha.

Arjuna listed the feats of Krishna to pacify Krishna who was angry.

> Vaisampayana continued, 'And when on account of the wrongs of Pritha's sons, Janardana had thus got into a passion, and seemed bent upon consuming all created things, Arjuna exerted himself to pacify him. **And beholding Kesava angry, Falguna began to recite the feats achieved in his former lives by that soul of all things**, himself immeasurable, the eternal one, of infinite energy, the lord of Prajapati himself, the supreme ruler of the worlds, Vishnu of profound wisdom!'

One of the feats he mentioned was about how he made Dwarka and how he will submerge it at the end.

> And, O Janardana, thou hast also appropriate unto thyself the sacred city of Dwarka, abounding in wealth and agreeable unto the Rishi themselves, and **thou wilt submerge it at the end within the ocean!**

How did Arjuna know that Dwarka would be submerged when it was thirteen years before the Kurukshetra war and Dwarka submerged 36 years after the war

Comment: The passage says Arjuna began to recite some of the feats that Krishna achieved in his previous lives. So, Arjuna was aware that Krishna submerged Dwarka in previous Kalpas. And since the events repeat themselves in each Kalpa the same Dwarka submerging event will occur in the present Kalpa too.